# Adding key Binding in e4 application

Tags: eclipse-rcp, key-bindings, e4

I am adding Key Bindings in Application.e4xmi. In Binding Tables (In window and Dialogs)->BindingTable->KeyBinding . in the Sequence Field I am taking M1+I, and in the Command Field I am putting Command ID When I run the application and press CTRL+I. the command is not executing.
Please help me.

Comment: What platform is this (Mac, Linux, Windows)? Have you defined a Handler for the command?

Comment: Windows. yes i have define a Handler for the command

Comment: Are you running the application from within Eclipse? I have had trouble with key bindings not working when run from Eclipse - but they work fine in the exported RCP.

Comment: Yes,I am running application within Eclipse

Comment: I am export RCP project but still key binding not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe it is a bit late to solve your problem - I had a similar one. This is what worked for me:

Eclipse 4 came to be known to erase commands not tagged with "type:user" (see https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/550175/).

Find the command in your Application.e4xmi and add the tag just like this:

```
<bindings xmi:id="_jC5aUCliEeWI4LgfuTRFhQ" elementId="your.command.id" keySequence="M1+I" command="_Bs2HEDgcEeSZkY-KjLWaPQ">
    <tags>type:user</tags>
</bindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an BindingContex

Create a BindingTable for this Context

Add your Binding

Add your BindingContext to your Window or Part

Comment: How to add key binding on Toolbar item

Comment: If you have added your BindingContext to your Part(That contains the Toolbar or not?) the Binding should work. Have you done all 4 Steps ?

Comment: I am not added key binding on part Toolbar, I am adding key binding on Workbench Window that contains toolbar and I have followed all the 4 step